# python version and python sys.path

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythonpath

I have anaconda installed and do not want to use the system python and its modules.

It is supposed that anaconda runs python in independent environment. However,

```
$ which python
/home/user/anaconda/bin/python

$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

$ ~/anaconda/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)
```

As you can see, `python` is linked to the system python of version 2.7.3, though `which` indicates that it is pointed to anaconda python.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys;
>>> from pprint import pprint as p
>>> p(sys.path)
['',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock-1.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing-2.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.pdfgui-1.0_r6798_20120508-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.utils-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.pdffit2-1.0_r6773_20111122-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.Structure-1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.pdfgetx-1.0_r2152_20130314-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rasterstats-0.7.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rasterio-0.24.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shapely-1.5.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum34-1.0.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snuggs-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cligj-0.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/affine-1.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click-4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/progress-1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py-2.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/user',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
```

It's natural that there are a lot of system path in python path. But for anaconda python,

```
$ ~/anaconda/bin/python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> 
>>> import sys
>>> from pprint import pprint as p
>>> p(sys.path)
['',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock-1.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing-2.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.pdfgui-1.0_r6798_20120508-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.utils-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.pdffit2-1.0_r6773_20111122-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.Structure-1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/diffpy.pdfgetx-1.0_r2152_20130314-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rasterstats-0.7.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rasterio-0.24.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shapely-1.5.9-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum34-1.0.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snuggs-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cligj-0.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/affine-1.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click-4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/progress-1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py-2.5.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/user',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-1.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flake8-2.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mccabe-0.3.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.1.1-py2.7.egg']
```

Still a lot of system path.

If I filter the sys.path by

`sys.path = filter(lambda (x): x.startswith('/home/user/anaconda'), sys.path)`
the python path is clean but there will be a lot of ImportErrors.

I have exported `$PYTHONPATH=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Execute `type python` to check for aliases (or functions).
2. Execute `hash -r` to renew the `$PATH` hashtable, then try `which` again.

In general, you're probably better off using `type` than `which`, since the former is a shell builtin and has access to the shell's PATH hash table, functions and aliases.

- If you specifically want to look for an external program (as `which` does), you can use

  ```
  type -p
  ```

  In other words, it's a more reliable `which`.
- If you want to find *all* locations of executable commands with a given name, you can use

  ```
  type -a
  ```

Comment: Awesome!!!That's tricky. `type python` gives `python is aliased to 'export PYTHONPATH=/soft/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages:${PYTHONPATH};/usr/bin/python'`. I'm overriding it. But why there are still some many system path even I run `/home/user/anaconda/bin/python` directly?

Comment: I got it. I run `python` and `PYTHONPATH` was contaminated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Python3, create a symlink to Python and pip on Debian-based Linus distributions.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your Conda environment and activate it?

Basically you need to be in a folder where you want to create a project, launch a terminal and setup the Conda environment

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

Here you can choose a name for your environment and setup the python version, anaconda and any other packages you need for this environment. Then Conda will install all those for you and will create the environment.

When you need to use the environment, just activate it by:

```
activate yourenvname
```

read more: https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/